# Node route not rendering correct URL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm building a MEAN stack app but am running into an issue where Angular isn't able to recognize the module at my rendered url so it's throwing an error and crashing before it can perform my front-end get request.

I wrote this code in my routes/index.js file where `table` is the view page.

```
router.get('/table/user/:id', function(req, res){
  User.findById(req.params.id).populate('entries').exec(function(err, entries){
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.render('table', { entries: entries})
    }
  });
});
```

Angular CAN perform the get req when it hits the url `/table` but the route is going to `/table/user/203029384029384`, the url of my Node request.  I feel like this should just be rendering `/table` but it's not.

What I need if for the router.get at `table/user/:id` to render `/table`. Seems like this code should do that, no? PLMK if I need to add any other project code for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You might be misunderstanding the way AngularJS renders pages - there will be a separate http request for the table data and the table html.  Then AngularJS will put the data into the html at the client side.

The ExpressJS code you offered will only respond to requests to `/table/user/xxxxx`, not `/table`.  So you will need to make a view router in Node/Express to render the view separately.  Then, you will also need to run a controller in AngularJS to splice the data into your view - the data is merged client side, not server side.

Comment: My problem is I'm not sure what that view router is supposed to look like. Once I get the user redirected to the correct view url I can handle the client side Angular data. Routes have me totally confused tho.

Comment: You can think of routes as "code which gets executed based on a URI sent to the server".  That's all it means.  You should have the Network tab open on Chrome developer tools to watch all the different routes get loaded.